# Open .blend in different mode?

Tags: append, sculpt

So I was in sculpt mode and I accidentally hit tab causing the mode to change to edit and this crashes blender. I cannot reopen the files because I assume they were autosaved in edit mode causing huge a lag spike. I tried disabling load UI, I tried append, I even loaded a recovery file but thats useless because it was from 5 hours ago. Whenever I load up the .blend or the .blend1 file it just eats up my RAM before crashing. Is there a way to force the .blend file to reopen in sculpt mode or am I screwed?

I'm using 2.8
I have 32GB of RAM and an 8-core CPU with a 1080ti GPU on Windows 10 64bit

Comment: You could try uploading it here, and seeing if someone else here can open the file - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new, empty project, go to Sculpt, then try to DragDrop import your broken .blend file. Then Choose "append". Or Choose File->Append... Then navigate to "object" Folder ("Mesh" didn't work for me). Choose your Mesh.

[image: choose append]

[image: go to object]

[image: choose object]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNqZy.jpg